# What is the difference between "vuose" and "vuole"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

Translation question

She didn't want to eat, my translation is "non vuole mangiare", which is wrong. The  answer given is "non vuose mangiare", which I haven't encountered till now. Is it a new tense? And why my answer is wrong? Grazie mille.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I have to give it to the first one even though both are very helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Non vuole mangiare" is wrong because it is present tense, whereas "she didn't want to eat" is simple past.

However, "Vuose" is not an Italian word. What you are looking for is the word "volle", the 3rd person singular of the passato remoto tense of the verb "volere".

So, the correct translation for "She didn't want to eat" is:

> Non volle mangiare.

If you need help with Italian tenses, I usually recommend this resource to my students: [ITALIAN VERBS](http://www.italian-verbs.com/italian-verbs.htm)

Answer (score 4):

"She didn't want to eat" is Simple Past, which in Italian is translated with either *Passato Prossimo* or *Passato Remoto* of the *Indicativo* form. You translated it with a *Presente*, which would be translated to "She doesn't want to eat."

The correct translations are *"Non volle mangiare"* or, the more frequently used, *"Non ha voluto mangiare"*.

Comment: Depending on context it can also be “non voleva mangiare” (*imperfetto*).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such verb form as *vuose* in Italian language. The exact translation is:

- *Non vuole mangiare*.    Indicativo Presente
- *Non volle mangiare*.    Indicativo Passato remoto
- *Non voleva mangiare*.   Indicativo Imperfetto.
- *Non ha voluto mangiare.* Indicativo Passato prossimo

Have a look on [italian-verbs.com](https://www.italian-verbs.com/verbi-italiani/coniugazione.php?parola=volere) or [verbix.com](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/Italian/volere.html) or alternatively on [The Big Book of Italian Verbs](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=DYynDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pp.  1043-1044)